# WIndows 8.1 not showing up on GRUB during boot up. Windows 8.1/Ubuntu 13.10 dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I have recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 along side Windows 8.1 on my Laptop. After the install of Ubuntu and restart, everything worked fine. Windows 8.1 showed up in GRUB when the PC restarted to finish Ubuntu installation, but when I restarted my computer later to go back to Windows 8.1, it doesn't show up in GRUB. I have read other forums and no one has the question that I have, they're similar, but aren't the right ones to help me. Please help!!

Comment: boot into ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub` command on the terminal.Now windows option will be shown on the grub.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am posting here from Windows 8 now. Although during the time I was away with Ubuntu, I must say I do quite enjoy it. I am glad I partitioned my drive so I can have both.

Comment: WHile I have you, is it possible for GRUB to identify a HDD connected via USB adapter as a bootable source?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/164759/how-to-boot-multiple-os-from-one-external-hard-drive